# severless version3 stage for httpApi gateway not working AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy lambda with http apigateway using serverless framework in AWS. I am unable to create stage , I have used stage and also tried stageName in provider section and also in httpApi event section.

Tried this

```py
provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: python3.9
  httpApi:
    stageName: dev # with stage as key also also
```

Tried this

```py
provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: python3.9
  stageName: dev   # with stage as key also also
```

Tried this functions:

```py
  get:
    handler: lambda.handler
    name: ci-test-result-lambda
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /results
          method: GET
          stage: dev  # also with stageName
          cors: true
```

Please help me how can I configure stage for http Api gateway using serverless framework for AWS

Answer (score 0):

The "stage" should be under provider tag. You can try this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: python3.9
```

by default this will be deployed to "dev" stage.
You can use this to deploy to other stages e.g. "prod"

```
sls deploy --stage prod
```

Reference:

- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: can you post your entire serverless.yaml? one good way is to start with a working example and add the stage option. you can use this: https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/v3/aws-python-http-api